# Chromedriver c# - no suitable constructor

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Hello guys how can I run Chromedriver with SERVICE,OPTIONS,PATH?

I have 8 constructors available but not even one is for those 3 parameters.

Thanks for answer.

I need this ,how can I achieve it?

```
public ChromeDriver(string chromeDriverDirectory,ChromeDriver service, 
ChromeOptions options);
```

[image]

Comment: From then constructors available, it's pretty clear that you're allowed to pass `chromeDriverDirectory` **or** `service`, so presumably they're mutually exclusive, or provide the same information. Indeed, looking at [the docs for `ChromeDriverService`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Chrome_ChromeDriverService_CreateDefaultService_1.htm), we can see that it can be constructed by passing in `driverPath`, which is the same thing as `chromeDriverDirectory`.

Comment: Thank you that explanation resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a constructor which takes SERVICE, OPTIONS, PATH.
The most similar to what you are looking for is this one:

```
public ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService service, ChromeOptions options);;
```

Usage:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

// Your configuration
// e.g. options.AddArgument("--disable-popup-blocking");

var driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService("PATH"), chromeOptions);
```